# NestJS Graphql subscription -- how to disconnect client?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, graphql-subscriptions, nestjs-graphql, graphql-ws

I've been looking like mad trying to find some API documentation on how to do this.

I'm using 9x versions of nestjs with `graphql-ws` 5.11.2 and `graphql-redis-subscriptions` 2.5.0 and `16.5.0` graphql.

I'm doing the code first approach which has this `resolve` hook in the decorator where the context can be accessed.

Decorator example:

```
@Subscription(() => SyncEvent, {
    resolve: (value: SyncEvent, args: any, context: any, info: any) => {...})}
public async syncEvents(): Promise<AsyncIterator<SyncEvent>> {
    return this.pubSubService.pubSub.asyncIterator(session.deviceId);
  }
```

pubSub being defined as an object of this class:

`RedisPubSub` coming from `graphql-redis-subscriptions` node module.

There are no indicated types for context/info, info has the graphql schema and other static information.

Context has a `req` key with `socket` and `client` and other metadata. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any .close() or .end() or .disconnect() methods anywhere on it.

Calling req.socket.end() however will crash the server which I guess is a disconnect but for everyone involved.

My end purpose is on a certain value being received to disconnect the client from the server.